# Golang struct pointer reference lost when calling struct property method

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I'm attempting to use a `struct` to manage accessing nodes on a tree. Whenever I access the method of the parent's child node, the parent reference on the subsequent call gets lost (i.e. `parent.child.method(child) -> [parent becomes nil]-> parent(the previous child).child ... etc`).

Here is the error snippet from my file.

```
type Node struct {
    Left *Node
    Right *Node
    value int
}

func (parent *Node) determineSide(child *Node) (Node, Node) {

    if child.Value < parent.Value {
        if parent.hasLeftNode() {
            return parent.Left.determineSide(child)
        }
        return parent.addLeftNode(child)

    } else if child.Value > parent.Value {
        if parent.hasRightNode() {
           return parent.Right.determineSide(child)
        }
        return parent.addRightNode(child)
    }
    return *child, *parent
 }
```

I attempted to solve this by trying to find a way to inform the method that the new reference should be `parent.Left`. Things like using `*parent.Left` and `&parent.Left` didn't seem to be correct.

A solution may might be to move this code outside of the `struct` and have another function handle the outcome for a quick fix, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working out of the box. Thought process here is influenced by using `this.child.determineSide(child)`.

Full code is [here](https://github.com/gellel/binarygo/blob/master/node/node.go).

**Edit**

Here is some output from the terminal that might give even further context. Looks like I'm having a check type issue leading to the problem.

```
parent &{<nil> <nil> 2}
parent.Left <nil>
parent.LeftNode true
child &{<nil> <nil> 1}
parent <nil>
child &{<nil> <nil> 1}
```

Comment: In the linked code your methods are returning concrete, ie non-pointer, struct values and also nowhere in the code are you returning `nil` or setting pointers to `nil`. So this `parent.child.method(child) -> [parent becomes nil]` *cannot* happen in the provided code. Please try to better explain what you mean by *"parent reference on the subsequent call gets lost"*. Also note that if you have a method `M` that returns its receiver, calling `a.b.M(c)` will return `b` and *not* `a`. ie. `parent.Left.determineSide(child)` will return `Left` as the parent.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding @mkopriva. So the last part of your comment captures the intended behaviour. Think of the function as a walk through a connected series of items (i.e. a graph, linked list, etc.). As you may have already imagined, as we go through the connected items we want the each check to be performed on the node we are visiting. For example, if we have already checked A, we want to then move onto site B. If B has a connected C we want to then check that. In my code, when we move from A to B, for whatever reason B comes a nil and then we cannot check for C.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, your code does not seem to be setting anything to nil therefore nothing can "become nil" by itself, it has to be nil from the get go. ie B doesn't become nil, it is nil from the beginning, whatever that B is. Please include the code that is actually printing out the output. Show how you're using the `node` package.

Comment: The issue is due to a type check error. The implementation of isNode is incorrectly implemented so when the type check unintentionally returns true, the subsequent call is accessing a nil memory address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay， I know what u'r exactly asking finally.

`New()`  methods returns a value, not a pointer, which means u can't see later change in caller. What the caller got is only a value copy of the Node. So the parent what u print will always be `{Left:<nil> Right:<nil> Value:2}`.

So the same with `addLeftNode()` and `addRightNode()`.

Just use pointer, not value to achieve your goal.

See [pointers_vs_values](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)

---

I think it's just the `Visit()` method where the problem is.

1. It will never visit right child when u immediately return after visited left child.
2. The left and right child are not mutually exclusive, so the second if-clause should not use `else if`, which would be `if`.
3. The visiting order also has problem.

Before:

```
// Visit will automatically walk through the Child Nodes of the accessed Parent Node.
func (parent *Node) Visit() (Node, int) {
    fmt.Println("Node value:", parent.Value)
    if parent.hasLeftNode() {
        return parent.Left.Visit()
    } else if parent.hasRightNode() {
        return parent.Right.Visit()
    }
    return *parent, parent.Value
}
```

Modified:

```
// Visit will automatically walk through the Child Nodes of the accessed Parent Node.
func (parent *Node) Visit() (Node, int) {
    if parent.hasLeftNode() {
        parent.Left.Visit()
    }
    fmt.Println("Node value:", parent.Value)
    if parent.hasRightNode() {
        parent.Right.Visit()
    }
    return *parent, parent.Value
}
```

Additionally, as to me, `Visit()` shouldn't return any values.

Comment: Hey @Bob Fred thanks for checking out some of the other code. This is good to know but I think you might have addressed a different problem. I'll try rephrase - i think i posed a bad question. What I'm attempting to solve is why when walking through a connected series of linked structs that when moving from say A to B, B becomes nil.

Comment: Just liked to follow on from that- thank you for fixing that up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem originated from incorrect type checking. The function successfully handled the call, but the method I was using wasn't accurate in confirming whether a node was assigned.

```
// isNode checks whether the provided property is a Node.
func (parent *Node) isNode(property interface{}, typeset interface{}) bool {

   fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(property) == reflect.TypeOf(typeset))
   // this always referred to the address for the base Node struct or similar falsy.
   return reflect.TypeOf(property) == reflect.TypeOf(typeset)
}

// hasLeftSide tests whether the Parent Node has a Node assigned to its left side.
func (parent *Node) hasLeftNode() bool {
    return parent.Left != nil //parent.isNode(parent.Left, (*Node)(nil))
}

// hasRightSide tests whether the Parent Node has a Node assigned to its right side.
func (parent *Node) hasRightNode() bool {
    return parent.Right != nil // parent.isNode(parent.Right, (*Node)(nil))
}
```